# Unitils and DBMaintainer - how to make them work with multiple users/schemas?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, ant, jdeveloper, unitils

I am working on a new Oracle ADF project, that is using Oragle 10g Database, and I am using Unitils and DBMaintainer in our project for:

- updating the db structure
- unittesting
- read in seed data
- read in test data
- List item

In our project, we have 2 schemas, and 2 db users that have privilegies to connect to these schemas. I have them in a folder structure with incremental names and I am using the @convention for script naming.

```
001_@schemaA_name.sql 
002_@schemaB_name.sql 
003_@schemaA_name.sql
```

This works fine with ant and DBMaintainer update task, and I supply the multiple user names by configuring extra  elements for the ant task.

```
<target name="create" depends="users-drop, users-create" description="This tasks ... ">
    <updateDatabase scriptLocations="${dbscript.maintainer.dir}" autoCreateDbMaintainScriptsTable="true">
       <database name="${db.user.dans}" driverClassName="${driver}" userName="${db.user.dans}" password="${db.user.dans.pwd}" url="${db.url.full}" schemaNames="${db.user.dans}" />
        <database name="idp" driverClassName="${driver}" userName="${db.user.idp}"
            password="${db.user.idp.pwd}" url="${db.url.full}" schemaNames="${db.user.idp}" />
    </updateDatabase>
</target>
```

However, I cant figure out, how to make the DBMaintainer update task create the xsd schemas from my db schemas?

So, I decided to use Unitils, since its update creates xsd schemas.
I haven't found any description or documentation for the Unitils ant tasks - can anyone give some hints?
For the time being I have figured out to run Unitils by creating a Junit test, with @Dataset annotation. I can make it work with one schema, and one db user. But I am out of ideas how to make it work with multiple users?

Here is the unitils-local.properties setup I have:

```
database.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@localhost\:1521\:vipu
database.schemaNames=a,b
database.userName=a
database.password=a1
```

Can any of you guys give me a tip, how to make Unitils work with the second user/schema ??
I will be extremely gratefull for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out how to make dbmaintain and unitils work together on multi-database-user support, but the solution is a pure ant hack.

1. I have set up the configuration for dbmaintain, using multi-database-user support.
2. I have made a unitils-local.properties file with token keys for replacement.
3. The init target of my ant script is generating a new unitils-local.properties file, by replacing tokens for username/password/schema with values that are correct for the target envirnonment, and then copies it to the users home directory.
4. I have sorted the tests into folders, that are prefixed with the schema name
5. When unitils is invoked, it picks up the unitils-local.properties file just created by the ant script, and does its magic.

Its far from pretty, but it works.

Comment: I was looking for a programmatic solution to this (to the extent of generating unitils.properties on-the-fly), but eventually reached a similar conclusion

Answer (score 3):

eventually I found a way to inject any unitil.properties of your choice --- by instantiating Unitils yourself!

You need a method that is evoked @BeforeClass, in which you perform something like the following:

```
@BeforeClass
public void initializeUnitils {
    Properties properties;
    ...
    // load properties file/values depending on various conditions
    ...
    Unitils unitils = new Unitils();
    unitils.init(properties);
    Unitils.setInstance( unitils );     
}
```

I choose the properties file depending on which hibernate configuration is loaded (via @HibernateSessionFactory), but there should be other options as well

Comment: Looks like this does not cover Injections such as `@TestDataSource private DataSource dataSource;` - the dataSource will be `null`. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html#From_Java_code

Specifically you may need to do something like:

```
databases.names=admin,user,read
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin://mydb:1521:MYDB
database.admin.username=admin
database.admin.password=adminpwd
database.admin.schemaNames=admin
database.user.userName=user
database.user.password=userpwd
database.user.schemaNames=user
database.read.userName=read
database.read.password=readpwd
database.read.schemaNames=read
```

Also this link may be helpful: http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html#Multi-database__user_support

Comment: Yes, I know of this multi-database DBMaintain configuration. The trouble is, that Unitils is using DBMaintain as a submodule, but seems not to honor the multi-database configuration.

Comment: Interesting.  Yeah, I've been having similar problems with Unitils' dbMaintain module not behaving the same as what is documented on dbMaintain's site.  See my question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143505/using-unitils-dbmaintain-to-maintain-database-how-to-exclude-scripts-from-being).  My assumption at this point is that Unitils is using an older version of dbMaintain.

Comment: Follow up: my assumption was correct.  Unitils is using an old version of dbMaintain under the covers.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6414416/411229

Answer (score 0):

I followed Ryan suggestion. I noticed couple changes when I debugged UnitilsDB.

Following is my running unitils-local.properties:

```
database.names=db1,db2
database.driverClassName.db1=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url.db1=jdbc:oracle:thin:@db1d.company.com:123:db1d
database.userName.db1=user
database.password.db1=password
database.dialect.db1=oracle
database.schemaNames.db1=user_admin

database.driverClassName.db2=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url.db2=jdbc:oracle:thin:@db2s.company.com:456:db2s
database.userName.db2=user
database.password.db2=password
database.dialect.db2=oracle
```

Make sure to use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database.db1") to connecto to particular database in your test case:

```
@RunWith(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database.db1")
@Transactional
@DataSet
public class MyDAOTest {

..

}
```