# Using unitils/dbMaintain to maintain database, how to exclude scripts from being run?

Tags: junit, integration-testing, unitils

I am using unitils (and its dbMaintain module) to maintain the state of my local database.

dbMaintain has an option to exclude/include scripts based on a qualifier.  See http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html#Qualifier_inclusion__exclusion.

In my project, excludes/includes do not work when running from a Unitils test with the `UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner`.

My script hierarchy:

```
unitils/ 
    01_create/ <lots of scripts here> 
    02_lkups/ <lots of scripts here> 
    03_#testdata/01_#testdata_master/05_#testdata_master_rate_offer.sql
```

My unitils.properties file has:

```
updateDataBaseSchema.enabled=true
dbMaintainer.script.locations=unitils
dbMaintainer.qualifiers=testdata 
dbMaintainer.excludedQualifiers=testdata
```

I would expect 05_#testdata_master_rate_offer.sql to be excluded. But it is being run.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by one of the unitils developers on the unitils forums here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/unitils/forums/forum/570578/topic/4546980

> Qualifiers are a feature of
>   dbmaintain. Unitils 3.1still contains
>   its own dbmaintainer which still dates
>   from before the split-off of
>   dbmaintain. Unitils 4.0 has this
>   module replaced by a dependency to
>   dbmaintain, but this version is not
>   released yet. I would suggest that,
>   until 4.0 is released, you call
>   dbmaintain directly from your java
>   code. Hope this helps, Filip